# Is this system of equations "solvable"?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

I've been trying to solve the following system of equations for $p_1>0$ and $p_2>0$, but have failed to do so (in a reasonable fashion). Can anybody confirm that this is indeed not possible or show me how?

$$
0\overset{!}{=}-{K}_1p_{1}^2-2{K}_2 p_{2} p_{1}-\delta_{1} p_{1}+1\\
0\overset{!}{=}-2{K}_1p_{1}p_{2}-{K}_2 p_{2}^2-\delta_{2} p_{2}+1
$$

where $K_i,\delta_i>0$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$.

The $+1$-term seems to ruin everything...

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The factors $2$ are placed asymmetrically. Is that intended ?

Comment: Wow I really should go to the eye doc.! Thanks...

Comment: Do you need an explicit solution or just to show that there are solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need an explicit solution.

Comment: Have a look at my update.

Comment: What does an exclamation point over an equal sign mean? If it means "not equal" then I observe $p_1=p_2=0$ satisfies both requirements  because $0 \neq 1$.

Comment: It stresses that this equation is to be shown for the correct$p&s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These equations represent two conics (hyperbolas if I am right), which don't seem to enjoy particular properties.

As the conics potentially have four intersection points, the problem is of the quartic type. Elimination of one of the unknowns should lead to a quartic polynomial, and there's no shortcut.

---

From the first equation, draw

$$2{K}_2 p_{2} p_{1}=-{K}_1p_{1}^2-\delta_{1} p_{1}+1.$$

Then multiply the second by $4K_2p_1^2$ to get

$$0=-4{K}_1p_1^22K_2p_{1}p_{2}-4K_2^2p_1^2p_{2}^2-2\delta_{2}p_12K_2p_1 p_{2}+4K_2p_1^2\\
=-4{K}_1p_1^2(-{K}_1p_{1}^2-\delta_{1} p_{1}+1)-(-{K}_1p_{1}^2-\delta_{1} p_{1}+1)^2-2\delta_{2}p_1(-{K}_1p_{1}^2-\delta_{1} p_{1}+1)+4K_2p_1^2,$$

the announced quartic.

Comment: Thanks that great! Looks like I will have to go down the numeric route...

Comment: @DrShredz: why ? There is an analytical solution.

Comment: You mean the really Long formula for quartic polynomials?

Comment: @DrShredz: yes. Contrary to common belief, it is tractable if you use intermediate variables. The depressed quartic factors as $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2-ax+c)$, which leads to a cubic equation. The cubic always has a real solution and you end-up with two quadratics.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out later and maybe the solution is a "nice" expression by surprise :)

Comment: @DrShredz: don't hope too much. You have four independent parameters, which is close to the maximum (five) for a quartic; so you are virtually in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the first equation and solving this for $p_2$:
 so
$$p_2=-\frac{K_1p_1}{2K_2}-\frac{\delta_1}{2K_2}+\frac{1}{2K_2p_1}$$ and plug this in the second one.
Should a post a result for you?

Comment: Thats what I tried but things then get super ugly, as $p_1$ is in the denominator. :(

Comment: @DrShredz: that problem *is* ugly, sorry.